Difficulty understanding "replace" combined with RE and scriptblock in Powershell
The script is designed to search for users located in $ListOfDismissedEmpl and doing something else...
$ListOfDismissedEmpl = "22261,24996,25340".Split(",")

$filter = $ListOfDismissedEmpl -replace '(.+)','samaccountname -like "`*`$1`*`"' -join ' -or '

$resUsersInact60 = Get-ADUser -filter $filter -Properties * | Select-Object ....

Could someone explain the lines to me:
$filter = $ListOfDismissedEmpl -replace '(.+)','samaccountname -like "`*`$1`*`"' -join ' -or '


I think you mean this without the backquotes $ListOfDismissedEmpl -replace '(.+)','samaccountname -like "*$1*"' -join ' -or '

alternatively replace the whole match -replace '.+','samaccountname -like "*$&*"'

The statement you've highlighted consists of a -replace operations chained with a -join operation, the result of which is assigned to $filter.
Let's try splitting the statement into two separate statements instead:
$temp = $ListOfDismissedEmpl -replace '(.+)','samaccountname -like "`*`$1`*`"' 

$filter = $temp -join ' -or '

The -replace operator takes 1 or more strings as input via the left-hand side operand, and applies the requested replace operation to each and outputs the results. In this case the lhs operand consists of the 3-item string array stored in $ListOfDismissedEmpl, and the operation will thus result in 3 new strings.
Let's apply the operation manually to se what the intermediate result is:
PS ~> $ListOfDismissedEmpl = "22261,24996,25340".Split(",")
PS ~> $ListOfDismissedEmpl -replace '(.+)','samaccountname -like "`*`$1`*`"'
samaccountname -like "`*`22261`*`"
samaccountname -like "`*`24996`*`"
samaccountname -like "`*`25340`*`"

As expected, the operation outputs 3 new strings, with the value captured by the implicit capture group (.+) embedded in each.
The -join operator then joins the 3 strings together, using -or as a separator, resulting in the final filter string:
PS ~> $temp = $ListOfDismissedEmpl -replace '(.+)','samaccountname -like "`*`$1`*`"'
PS ~> $temp -join ' -or '
samaccountname -like "`*`22261`*`" -or samaccountname -like "`*`24996`*`" -or samaccountname -like "`*`25340`*`"

So the final value of $filter will be the string:
samaccountname -like "`*`22261`*`" -or samaccountname -like "`*`24996`*`" -or samaccountname -like "`*`25340`*`"


If you're having problems when using the filter value in conjunction with Get-ADUser (eg. errors about the syntactical validity of the filter or getting no meaningful search results back) then it's probably because of all the unnecessary backticks `.
Try removing them from the substitution string (the second string of the right-hand side operand) and you should get a valid filter string:
$filter = $ListOfDismissedEmpl -replace '(.+)','samaccountname -like "*$1*"' -join ' -or '

The substitution string is defined using a single-quoted string literal, meaning $1 won't be expanded and interpolated - thus no need to escape the $

Thank you very much for your explanation. I learned a lot - I also appreciate your time. How can I buy a beer?
I realized that I still think in a very linear way in programming. That is, -join -or -replace is treated as operators that are supposed to return something so that it can be referred to again later - such static, one-line thinking. This is not the case here, the code ($filter) is created for the purpose of the (-filter) code.
Additionally, in PS -replace runs through the list as it wants, it doesn't worry about -or on the last element, and in Python, which I know better, replace works much more poorly with one string, more than that it has loops and you have to remember to remove -or during the last iteration
Well, here are the eyes:
The -join operator then joins the 3 strings together, using -or as a separator.
Thank you
